# Variable width for second level ul in Nicemenu (Drupal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

I have a menu structure like the below in Drupal 7. This is a part of the Nicemenu module in Drupal. I am applying a width to the second level ul - the sub menu ul, and this gets applied to all the second level ul. What I need is a variable width for the second level ul's. All these HTML sre dynamically generated by Drupal and I may not be able to hard code any classes or ID to these second level uls. I targeted these using pseudo-classes but didn't achieve what I want.

Here's the HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="first leaf"><a class="active" href="">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li class="expanded"><a title="" href="">Menu 2</a>
        <ul class="menu"> <!--This should have width of 200px-->
        <li class="first leaf"><a href="">Menu 2a</a></li>
        <li class="last leaf"><a href="">Menu 2b</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="expanded"><a title="" href="">Menu 3</a>
<ul class="menu"><!-- Width should be 350px-->
            <li class="first leaf"><a href="">Menu 3a</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="">Menu 3b</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="">Menu 3c</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="">Menu 3d</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="">Menu 3e</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="">Menu 3f</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="">Menu 3g</a></li>
            <li class="last leaf"><a href="">Menu 3h</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="expanded"><a title="" href="">Menu 4</a>
            <ul class="menu"><!-- Width should be 200px-->
            <li class="first expanded"><a title="" href="">Menu 4a</a><ul class="menu">
            <li class="first last leaf"><a href="">Menu 4a-1</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="last leaf"><a href="">Menu 4b</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="leaf"><a href="">Menu 5</a></li>
    <li class="expanded"><a title="" href="">Menu 5a</a>
    <ul class="menu"><!-- Width should be 150px-->
<li class="first last leaf"><a href="">Menu 5b</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="leaf"><a href="">Menu 6</a></li>
    <li class="leaf"><a href="">Menu 7</a></li>
    <li class="expanded"><a title="" href="">Menu 8</a>
            <ul class="menu"><!-- Width should be 200px-->
            <li class="first leaf"><a href="">Menu 8</a></li>
            <li class="last leaf"><a href="">Menu 9</a></li>
            </ul></li>
    <li class="last leaf"><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need `id` attributes in your `<ul>` elements, so you can use CSS to set the widths for each `id`. This is the most convenient and robust way to style separate HTML elements.

[Add html ID to content field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16879/add-html-id-to-content-field) shows a solution how to add these `id` attributes.

Comment: Hey..I know all these basics. It's happening in Drupal and may not be able to hard code the css id's. All needs to be done dynamically.

Comment: The answer of the question I linked handles (dynamically) generating ID for HTML elements.